# Ray with Kubernetes: How to connect to Ray from outside the Kubernetes cluster (e.g. from a flask app)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flask, ray

I have a flask app in a Docker container.  I need to do CPU/GPU intensive work so I created a Kubernedes cluster with a Ray head and Ray worker nodes.  My flask app is not part of this Kubernedes cluster and is on a distinct EC2 instance.  In theory, it would be nice to call ray.init("IP address of Ray head node") and ray.remote functions from the flask app, but I am currently unable to connect to the cluster. Right now I am using a Docker container for my flask app and using the default Ray Docker images rayproject/ray-ml:2.0.0 and rayproject/ray-ml:2.0.0-gpu in the cluster node groups.  I see a few options:

1. We should continue using separate docker images for the web app vs. kubernedes nodes and we should continue hosting the flask app outside of the kubernedes cluster.  This is the ideal scenario because it is the status quo, the problem is I can't seem to connect to the cluster via ray.init.  I have tried with both the public IP address of the EC2 instance that has the Ray Head node and I have tried creating a "Service" of type "LoadBalancer" in the kubernedes YAML config and using ray.init("ray://URL.elb.amazonaws.com:6379") and neither can connect.  I'm pretty sure my security groups should allow access.
2. We should continue using separate docker images for the web app vs. kubernedes nodes and put the flask app in the kubernedes cluster.

Can someone guide me as to which is the correct option and given that option how to get it working given the bugs I am seeing?

Here are some assumptions I'm making if this affects the answer to me question:

1. Best practice is to have a separate docker container for the ray nodes and the flask app.
2. The ray.remote function code does NOT need to be in the docker images for the ray worker or head nodes, but does have to be in the docker image for the flask app.  This code is passed over the network from the flask app to the Ray nodes via Ray (it is not passed over every time the function is called, but in a more efficient way).
3. The pip dependencies that the ray.remote functions depend on MUST be in the docker images of the ray worker nodes.  The pip dependencies that the ray.remote functions depend on NEED NOT be in the docker image of the Ray head node or the flask app. Thus, if we use requirements not included on the default Ray docker images ("rayproject/ray-ml:2.0.0", "rayproject/ray-ml:2.0.0-gpu"), we must create a new docker image using the default Ray docker image as a base image and add the additional dependencies.

Comment: Can you run the Flask application inside the Kubernetes cluster, and then connect to a ClusterIP-type Service name?  That would avoid the networking problems you seem to be having, and also let you stop maintaining the additional EC2 instance.

Comment: "but I am currently unable to connect to the cluster": Why? Generally you can use an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource to expose a service on a public address, although there are situations in which that isn't possible (e.g., the cluster doesn't have a public address).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this.  Apparently, when you use "kind: RayCluster" in the YAML file, it automatically creates a service.  Then you can connect to that service via ray.init("ray://raycluster-project-head-svc:10001") (whatever the service name is).  Since I didn't know about this service, I was trying to create my own service or connect directly to the Ray head IP and it wasn't connecting with that.